# I want to show My Json Data in Listview in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, listview, builder

I want to show all my json data in listview. But the problem is, when I want to get idEmployee, officeID, avater and fullName in listview then it shows error.

> type 'String' in not a subtype of type 'int'.

When I want to show only fullName using FutureBuilder, if I commented all variable without fullName in model class, it works fine. But when I want to add without fullName any other data, it shows error.

Here is the json data that I want to show in listview:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "count": 259,
        "data": [
            {
                "idEmployee": 3559,
                "avatar": "f8b8ad832a591db9c86a157a3739d98b.jpg",
                "fullName": "A X C",
                "officeID": "1003559",
                "email": "",
                "designation": "Account Manager",
                "department": "Accounts",
                "mobileNumber": "",
                "workStation": "Software Office",
                "businessUnit": "EMD"
            }
        ]
    },
    "id": 2899
}
```

Here is my model class:

```
class ListAlbum {
  final int idEmployee;
  final String avatar;
  final String fullName;
  final int officeID;
  final String email;
  final String designation;
  final String department;
  final String mobileNumber;
  final String workStation;
  final String businessUnit;

  ListAlbum({
    required this.idEmployee,
    required this.avatar,
    required this.fullName,
    required this.officeID,
    required this.email,
    required this.designation,
    required this.department,
    required this.mobileNumber,
    required this.workStation,
    required this.businessUnit,
  });

  factory ListAlbum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ListAlbum(
      idEmployee: json['idEmployee'],
      avatar: json['avatar'],
      fullName: json['fullName'],
      officeID: json['officeID'],
      email: json['email'],
      designation: json['designation'],
      department: json['department'],
      mobileNumber: json['mobileNumber'],
      workStation: json['workStation'],
      businessUnit: json['businessUnit'],
    );
  }
}
```

This is my full code.

Now I want to create and add listview in Scaffold with data by solving these errors. How can I create this listview?

```
class OrganizationList extends StatefulWidget {
  const OrganizationList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OrganizationListState createState() => _OrganizationListState();
}

class _OrganizationListState extends State<OrganizationList> {
  late Future<ListAlbum> futureAlbum;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureAlbum = listData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<ListAlbum>(
          future: futureAlbum,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              print(snapshot.data);
              return Text(snapshot.data!.fullName);
              // return Text(snapshot.data!.officeID.toString());   // in this line error shows. type 'String' in not a subtype of type 'int'
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('${snapshot.error}');
            }
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<ListAlbum> listData() async {
  final token = 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjI4OTksImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vcG9ydGFsLWFwaS5qb21ha2hhdGEuY29tL2FwaS9hdXRoL2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNjI5NTI2OTc1LCJleHAiOjE2Mjk2MTMzNzUsIm5iZiI6MTYyOTUyNjk3NSwianRpIjoiRktiT295eEYwaEpDUXMxdiJ9.o4eM_C4hlluHe9Azk0MspPJtYZ7agdpFA6xwKiijLj8';
  String url =
      'https://portal-api.jomakhata.com/api/getOrganizationData?token=${token}';

  Dio dio = new Dio();
  dio.options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
  final body = {'limit': 10, 'orderBy': 'idEmployee', 'orderType': 'DESC'};
  final response = await dio.post(url, data: body);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.data);
    var data = ListAlbum.fromJson(response.data["data"]["data"][0]);
    return data;
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed!');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your json data, your `officeID` is a string `"officeID": "1003559",`

but in `ListAlbum` the attribute is defined as an integer `final int officeID;`

Change `final int officeID;` in `ListAlbum` to `final String officeID;`

And `.toString()` won't be required any more.

### Updated

The question author requested help to create listview in Scaffold to show those data. Here is that code:

```
Future<List<ListAlbum>> listData() async {
  final token = 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjI4OTksImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vcG9ydGFsLWFwaS5qb21ha2hhdGEuY29tL2FwaS9hdXRoL2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNjI5NTI2OTc1LCJleHAiOjE2Mjk2MTMzNzUsIm5iZiI6MTYyOTUyNjk3NSwianRpIjoiRktiT295eEYwaEpDUXMxdiJ9.o4eM_C4hlluHe9Azk0MspPJtYZ7agdpFA6xwKiijLj8';
  String url =
      'https://portal-api.jomakhata.com/api/getOrganizationData?token=${token}';

  Dio dio = new Dio();
  dio.options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
  final body = {'limit': 10, 'orderBy': 'idEmployee', 'orderType': 'DESC'};
  final response = await dio.post(url, data: body);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.data);
    List<Map<String,dynamic>> data = response.data["data"]["data"];
    List<ListAlbum> albums = data.map((json) => ListAlbum.fromJson(json)).toList();

    
    return albums;
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed!');
  }
}
```

Proceed to then edit your `FutureBuilder<ListAlbum>` to `FutureBuilder<List<ListAlbum>>` and return a `Listview.builder`. More info on how to use `Listview.builder` https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/long-lists

Comment: Thank you. i understood. what was my problem. it was a silly mistake for me. 

can u please help me to create listview in Scaffold to show those data?

Comment: in this line >List<ListAlbum> albums = data.map((json) => ListAlbum.fromJson(json));

there is an error  "A value of type 'Iterable<ListAlbum>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<ListAlbum>'.  Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'List<ListAlbum>'. "

Comment: sorry for inconvenience, i have edited it